# Redimension de imagenes en canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas

Tengo un canvas de ancho 340 y de alto 450, en donde le añado una imagen ocupando el 100% del canvas añadí una función de al pinchar me sacase las coordenadas pero el problema que tengo es que necesito las coordenadas de la imagen original no la redimensionada en el canvas por tanto tengo dudas de si con alguna operación matemática tipo restar el alto original menos el alto de la redimensionada y sumárselo a los coordenadas que obtengo serian las coordenadas reales o no

mi canvas es este

```
<canvas id="canvas" ngDefaultControl width="340" height="450" title = "click and drag to add 
rectangles" (click)="hijoClicked($event)" style="border:1px solid #000000;cursor:crosshair " ></canvas>
```

la redimension la creo aqui

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
const width = canvas.width;
const height= canvas.height;
self.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
self.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width,height);
```

[image: Original]

[image: Redimensionada con canvas]

Comment: No creo que pueda funcionar porque no estás escalando la imagen, la estás distorsionando. Tendrías que pasar como parámetro las dimensiones reales de la imagen y hacer un calculo.

Comment: Si la escalas respetando las proporciones de la imagen, el cálculo debería ser más intuitivo.